# How to chain where and where not in in sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have these two queries working:

```
var queryOne = client.query("SELECT * FROM tableone WHERE (tableone.id) NOT 
  IN ( SELECT tabletwo.id FROM tabletwo)");
var queryTwo = client.query("SELECT * FROM tableone WHERE time = 1")
```

I am attempting to combine them into one query:

```
var finalQuery = client.query("SELECT * FROM tableone WHERE time = 1 AND
  WHERE (tableone.id) NOT IN ( SELECT tabletwo.id FROM tabletwo)");
```

However, I am running into this error: syntax error at or near "WHERE"

How can I correctly, combine the two queries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

drop the second `WHERE`, it's not needed:

```
var finalQuery = client.query("SELECT * FROM tableone WHERE time = 1 AND 
(tableone.id) NOT IN ( SELECT tabletwo.id FROM tabletwo)");
```